# How to update multiple rows of multiple columns with single value having same condition for every column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table having different type of Fees like security fees, tuition fees, admission fees etc and all of these column accept null values too.

I want to update all null values of these columns with 0 value. I can write different update query for each column but because condition and value for all the columns is same I wanna learn to do it in a single update query.

```
Table_Fees
securityFees | TuitionFees | AdmissionFees
 150            500             null
 null           450              120
 150            null             120
```

How can I replace all null values with zero?

```
Update Table_Fees
 set securityFees = 0,
     TuitionFees  = 0,
     AdmissionFees = 0
where securityFees = null 
and   TuitionFees  = null
and   AdmissionFees = null;
```

or/and both operator are not useful in this case

PS: I can't change the structure of table. I can only replace null values with 0 through coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the answer by CASE

```
Update Table_Fees
 set securityFees = CASE when securityFees = null then 0 else securityFees END,
     TuitionFees  = CASE when TuitionFees  = null then 0 else TuitionFees  END,
     AdmissionFees = CASE when AdmissionFees = null then 0 else AdmissionFees END;
```

Answer (score 3):

if you use MySQL

```
Update Table_Fees
 set securityFees = IFNULL(securityFees,0),
     TuitionFees  = IFNULL(TuitionFees,0),
     AdmissionFees = IFNULL(AdmissionFees,0)
where securityFees is null 
or   TuitionFees  is null
or   AdmissionFees is null;
```

Comment: Function IFNULL could not be located

Comment: I removed the IFNULL and it zeroed the complete row instead of updating that single value

Answer (score 1):

```
Update Table_Fees
set securityFees = IFNULL(securityFees,0),
    TuitionFees  = IFNULL(TuitionFees,0),
    AdmissionFees = IFNULL(AdmissionFees,0)

// 3 individual querys

Update Table_Fees
set securityFees = 0
where securityFees is null;

Update Table_Fees
set TuitionFees = 0
where TuitionFees is null;

Update Table_Fees
set AdmissionFees = 0
where AdmissionFees is null;
```

No need for where condition if it has to updated in entire table.

Hope this works for you.

Let me know if any problem

Comment: Function IFNULL could not be located

Comment: I did this, create table zero(zero int); insert into zero(zero) values (0);

Comment: Update Table_Fees
 set securityFees = (select zero from zero where Table_Fees.securityFees  = null),
     TuitionFees  = (select zero from zero where Table_Fees.TuitionFees    = null),
     AdmissionFees = (select zero from zero where Table_Fees.AdmissionFees     = null);

Comment: But it only updating last SET column as 0 and replacing others with null

Comment: do you want it in one query or 3 would do

Comment: It is working absolutely fine at my end IFNULL is not giving error

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. I'm running queries at SAS platform so it may cause that it's not working at my end. Anyway I've found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Run this and you will get output scrips as required.

```
SELECT 'UPDATE yourtable SET ' + name + ' = NULL WHERE ' + name + ' = '''';'
FROM syscolumns
WHERE id = object_id('yourtable')
  AND isnullable = 1;
```